# Javascript state flow visualizer free

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, state, workflow

I'am looking at a javascript free library to visualize my status workflow in a web page.

i find several ones on web but are all too complex.

i have datasource from table with only two columns: StartStatus and DestinationStatus and want to visualize it in that way

[image: https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/OzKS67LoGJGc4l8Iux99Zp-8mKS9Z7OLEyES]

someone know a library to make that?

thanks